# titillium web and Raleway google font is not working

Tags: html, css, fonts

I am want to use titillium web and Raleway google font in by website  but it is not working

this is my html

```
> <head> <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/cssfamily=Raleway|Titillium+Web"rel="stylesheet">
> </head>
```

this is css

```
.bigheadline {
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-size: 10em;
  margin: 0;
}
.subheadline {
  font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 200;
  font-size: 3em;
  margin: 10px 0 0 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your URL is malformed; it is missing a `?` between `css` and `family`. It would also be good practice to add a space before `rel="stylesheet`. Try the following.

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway|Titillium+Web" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: no there is space between link and href . i changed it

Comment: Your font URL was malformed. I've edited my answer with a correct font import tag.